# Converting Redis String to binary

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to store data in redis using bitfield. The string I get is `"|\x00\x82"` I tried converting ASCII characters to binary with this

```
for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    let byte = map[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
    bString += byte;
  }
```

The result of this is `01111100 00000000 11111111 11111101` But there are only three characters in the string. the first two match and I don't know what are the other two. It doesn't even change when i try to store something else yet in redis-cli it changes. I noticed that this happens when the most significant bit is 1. I tried it with unsigned and signed integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read and write binary data in Redis, you can uses buffers with Node Redis:

```js
await redis.set('foo', Buffer.from([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]))
let result = await redis.get(commandOptions({ returnBuffers: true }), 'foo')

console.log(result) // <Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05>
```

Comment: charCodeAt() was the problem. When was the first bit 1 the return was 2 byte insted of one